# Most intelligent way of setting up partitions on SSD and HDD when dual booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, ssd

I'm in the process of buying a new laptop for my university studies in computer science and software engineering.

I'm planning to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 because I'd like to play games and use Ubuntu for my studies. In my config, I have a 1TB (5400rpm) **hard drive** and a 512GB **m.2 SSD**.

I'd like (if possible) to have both OSs to boot on the SSD. As for the HDD, it would be used as storage.

Where it gets complicated for me is deciding how all the partitions are going to be set up! In between FAT32 and NTFS for Windows, ext4 for Linux, the home, swap and / partitions etc...

What seems to be the **best option**? What **size** should I allocate for each of them? Can I **read** files from the other operating system I'm currently on?

-- PLANNED SPECS --

- i5 6600
- GTX 1060
- 16GB RAM

Comment: Is Windows 10 going to use the hard drive or SSD? Also, how much RAM do you have? Please add this info to your answer.

Comment: So Windows 10 is on the hard drive?

Comment: I'd like to have them both on the SSD (if possible) (for boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of depends on how much space you want for your Windows 10 programs, your Ubuntu programs, and your files. Windows creates two partitions, and Ubuntu can use 1-3 partitions. Here's a diagram of a good setup for you:
[image: Partition layout]
Leave the System Reserved partition alone. The second partition is where Windows is installed. The third partition is where Ubuntu will install and the fourth partition is where your personal files (documents or whatever) in Ubuntu will be stored. If you're not going to use more than 16 GB of RAM (you probably won't), don't make a swap partition. I recommend adjusting the sizes of these partitions to fit your needs. As for file system compatibility, Ubuntu can access NTFS partitions, but Windows needs special software to access ext4 drives.

Comment: So should I put my linux /home partition on the hard drive or just leave everything linux on the SSD?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: Thanks man!! Would you be okay if I ask any more questions later on during the week?

Comment: Sure. That's what this site is for.

Comment: You say that I ont need swap, but isn't that used for hibernation?

Comment: Yes. So if you want hibernation, you'll have to make a swap partition that's as big as the amount of RAM you use. For example, if you use only 8GB of RAM, your swap will be 8GB.

Comment: Maybe a swap file would also be good to setup, so that the swap space isn't always reserved/lost.

Comment: When I left that comment, Ubuntu didn't support swap files. Now it does, though, and it's good to have.